# PHP - How do you use spaces in mail() subject?

Tags: php, email

How can send an email with spaces in subject?

This is the problem; if I try to send an email like this (below) without spaces in the subject it will send successfully:

```
mail("$email",ThanksforSubscribe,$name,"From: address@gmail.com\n");
```

...but if I put spaces in the subject it fails:

```
mail("$email",Thanks for Subscribe,$name,"From: address@gmail.com\n");
```

I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR) in subscribe2.php on line 23

Complete code:

```
<?php
// display form if user has not clicked submit
if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  ?>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
  Name: 
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>

  Email: <input type="text"" name="email"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <?php 
} else {    // the user has submitted the form
  // Check if the "from" input field is filled out
  if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
    $email = $_POST["email"]; // sender
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
    $name = wordwrap($name, 70);
    // send mail
    mail("yourname@googlemail.com",subscribe,$name,"From: $email\n");
    mail("$email",ThanksforSubscribe,$name,"From: yourname@gmail.com\n");
    echo "Thank you ";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: put the string inside `""`

Comment: String should be enclosed in a quotes.

Comment: Learning basic PHP syntax rules would be a good start: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 mail($email,"Thanks for Subscribe",$name,"From: yourname@gmail.com\n");
```

Put it into "" or ''. Like this, PHP knows that this is a String.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put it in a string:

```
mail($email, 'Thanks for subscribing.', $name, "From: example@gmail.com\n");
```

Also of note, you don't need to put that first parameter in a string, as it is only a variable.

Answer (score 1):

try with :

```
mail($email,"Thanks fo Subscribe", $name, "From: example@gmail.com\n");
```